# Apple Music play and pause delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-music

I have integrated Apple Music in project. When i play or pause it takes delay of 2-3 seconds to come in effect. For example if i pause song it pauses after 1-2 second. I am using following methods to play and pause.
To Play :

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] prepareToPlay]; 
[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] play];
```

To Pause:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] pause];
```

How can i remove this delay?

Comment: I have no answer, but confirm that I am experiencing the same delays when my app runs on iOS 11.  My app has no delays when run on iOS 10.  I have another app which uses applicationMusicPlayer instead of systemMusicPlayer, and it has no delays on iOS 11.